# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on VMWare - Problems with Full Screen and Copy Pasting options

Tags: 14.04, vmware-workstation

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on VMWare workstation. I had the VMWare tools installed as well the open-vm-tools:i386.

I had to increase my disk size, and for that reason I booted a live gparted CD, and resized the partitions.

However, ever since then, the copy/paste and the fullscreen stopped working. I have treid reinstalling the VMWare tools and the open-vm-tools:i386, but it did not help.

Any suggestions?

Note that the Copy/paste is enabled in the guest isolation settings.